# c++ parameter constructor evaluation

Tags: c++, constructor, parameterized

How does below program evaluates to following? 1. How is the parameterized constructor evaluated? left to right ?

ZA (int n)0  ---> base class constructor called.

ZA (int n)2  --> how does m_i = 2 here?

ZA (int n)0 ----> constructor for ZA member variable defined in Zb called

ZA (int n)0

ZB (int n)2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ZA
{
public:
    ZA(int n = 0) : m_i(n) 
    {
        std::cout <<"ZA (int n)" <<m_i<<endl;
        ++m_i;
    }
protected:
    int m_i;
};

class ZB : public ZA
{
public:
    ZB(int n = 5) : m_a(new ZA[2]), m_x(++m_i)
    {
        std::cout <<"ZB (int n)" <<m_i<<endl;
    }
    ~ZB() 
    {
        delete [] m_a; 
    }
private:
    ZA m_x;
    ZA *m_a;
};

int main(void)
{
    ZB b;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens:

- `ZB(0)` is called but does not run
- base constructor `ZA(0)` is called => "*ZA (int n)0*" and `m_i = 1`
- initializers are processed **in the order of fields declaration**:

  - `m_x(++m_i)` is evaluated with ++1=2 => "*ZA (int n)2*" and `m_i = 2`
  - `m_a(new ZA[2])` is evaluated and create the two ZA instances => "*ZA (int n)0*" twice
- finally the ZB constructor is run => "*ZB (int n)2*"

Comment: Why when there is an "_" inside "**" the stars appear? :(

Comment: try putting code literals in backtick quotes, `like_this`, then *`it_works`*.

Comment: @Yakk: thanks for the info, I've edited my answer, much better with code highlight. :)